# Discord.JS Join To Create Temp VC to Delete

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want when a user is joining this temp channel to rename the channel as his `Name#0000 - Discord_ID` and when leaving from this temp vc to get deleted. How it can be done?

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    if (newState.channelID === 'channelID') { // You can also use `newState.channelID`
        newState.guild.channels.create("Tester", {
            type: 'voice',
            parent: 'categoryID'
        }).then(vc => {
            newState.setChannel(vc);
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heres the code to make it name the channel with the member name, and delete it after leaving, i edited your code a bit

```
    client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
        if (newState.channel?.name === 'Replace with channel name') { // You can also use `newState.channelID`
            newState.guild.channels.create(`${newState.member.user.username}#${newState.member.user.discriminator}`, {
                type: 'GUILD_VOICE',
                parent: 'Replace with category id',
            }).then(vc => {
                newState.setChannel(vc);
            })
            }
            if (oldState.channel?.name === `${oldState.member.user.username}#${oldState.member.user.discriminator}`) {
                oldState.channel?.delete()

        }
    });
```

---

Just make sure to put the channel name, and the category id!

---

Also, those "?" in the codes are for typescript, if you're using JavaScript, then you won't need them.

Comment: `?.` is an operator. It checks if the last value is nullish and doesn't continue if it is (prevents typeerrors). It is also in javascript

Comment: @MrMythical, Ahaa, thank you! :D